# Emulating a windows environment

Tags: windows, emulators

Is there an emulator available for Android that mimics a windows environment? WINE for Android does not look like it will be out for a while, and those that I've found don't look like they support past Windows 98 (our software requires XP S3 and up) due to different processor structures. It doesn't have to be a free option; as long as it's not too expensive, we don't mind paying. If we cannot do this we can use LogMeIn, but that is not preferable.

Comment: Fast forward to 2022, looks like [Wine for Android](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/android/) is still active.