# Is there a way to get this version of Hackenbush on an Android device?

Tags: installation

The game Hackenbush is a fun, two-player game from combinatorial game theory, an area of mathematics.

I am aware of [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.file.hackenbush); it scratches an itch. But I'm after more.

The following programme was written for Mac and Windows:

http://geometer.org/hackenbush/index.html

I wonder whether it could be adapted to an Android device.

### Context:

I don't know where to start. I had some success here with a different mathematical software though. See [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203261/234367). I know next to nothing about programming outside the very niche software GAP, based on C.

I hope that's enough context.

---

Please help :)

Comment: Looks like that program is not open-sourced, so I'm afraid there's no way to adapt it from the source other than trying to reverse-engineer it (development question is off-topic here though). The alternative is [Emulating a Windows environment](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49982/44325) and [Can Android run .exe file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43763/44325) which doesn't look promising either (or it's outdated).

Comment: I'd accept an answer that details how to run Hackenbush in an emulated Windows environment, @AndrewT.